# How add scroll horizontal in my page html to change opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I developed my page in html. I would like to add a scroll horizontally to change opacity of my picture and the time displayed in my page by moving the scroll. Can I add a scroll with css3 or javascript? Or must I use jquery? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

So one quick response. You never "MUST" use jquery. It is just a javascript library. So if it can be done with jquery, it can be done with javascript. What you can do is add a scroll, and then on change, select the picture and change the css value of it to be equal to the slider. something like this:

```
$("#slider").on("change", function(){
    val = $(this).val() / maxSliderValue;
    $("#picture").css("opacity", val)
})
```

Depending on what slider you are using, there should be a way of getting the max value from it.

$("#slider") gets the slider by the id of the slider.
the .on("change", function(){...}) calls a function when the slider that you selected changes. 
the val = $(this).val()/maxSliderValue gets the slider of the value that is changed and divides it by the max slider. I do this because if the value of the slider is 50, and the max value is 100, it will give 50/100 = 0.5 which is the opacity I am assuming you would have wanted.
$("#picture").css("opacity", val) sets the opacity attribute of the slider to the value we just calculated. Same logic as the first part for selecting.

Comment: what is the library i will must add it ?

Comment: I was referring to jquery. The code I wrote uses jquery.

Comment: I never worked with Jquery , can you explain me step by step please ?

Comment: Thank you very much , i will try it now . I think i must learn jquery before trynig this :) .

Comment: No problem. Good luck. It should be pretty easy to add jquery and get it working. Let me know if you need help. If my answer solves your problem, can you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can update opacity value for an image.

```js
$(function() {
  let elem = '#range';
  $(elem).on('mousemove keydown', function() {
    let img = '#img1';
    let value = $(this).val();
    $(img).css('opacity', value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg' width='300' height='300' id='img1' />
<br>
<input type='range' min='0.1' max='1' step='0.1' id='range' autofocus>
```

For info. on jQuery event handlers refer https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp

Hope, this simple demo might help you.. :)

Comment: At the same time, time and opacity must change by moving the scroll.

Comment: opacity changes  but which time you have not mentioned it in your problem stated above??

Comment: time?? do you want to change time w.r.t opacity factor using scroll

Comment: for example now i have the Time 10:05 am , i want when i move the scroll the time for example change 18:00 and the opacity become darker because the time night. I hope you understand me :)

Comment: do you really want to change image brightness to dark so that it is invisible at night time... and brighter during day time... something like that

Comment: I want do somthing like th timezone.io demo . th scroll on the top left of the page . you can see here https://timezone.io/team/buffer